# Successive 'the's

Tags: articles

I saw successive 'the's three times this week. Unfortunately I didn't take a note of them as I thought it's a mistake to write successive 'the's. However, I encountered one on [the BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/towards-advanced/unit-9/session-2)

> hub: a place which is **the the** centre of a particular activity

I don't think this is a mistake as they're usually careful editing. I looked up my grammar book, English Grammer in Use (5th edition) and there's nothing about successive 'the's (from  unit 73 to 78).

When and how is it correct to write multiple, successive 'the's?

Comment: I am fairly (99%) certain that is a typo. The BBC staff are humans like the rest of us and occasionally make mistakes. As far as I know there's no grammatically valid use for "the the", and I've personally committed this exact typo before, so I'm pretty confident about that being the issue here. A professional proofreader really should have caught it though.

Comment: @Dmann I agree, it's a typo. However you try to say the sentence, it doesn't make sense with **the the**.  I too can come up with no valid sentence other than something like *The the at the beginning of this sentence is the definite article.* On the other hand **that that** is possible, see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-do-you-handle-that-that-the-double-that-problem

Comment: There is an English post-punk band called **the The**, whose 1983 album _Soul Mining_ I am very fond of.

Comment: Some sources capitalise the first 'the'; others do not.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey i like british punk bands, will listen their tunes. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dmann has said in a comment, that example is almost certainly a typo.  But *the*, like probably any word, can be used as a noun.  When it's used as a noun, it can be preceded by a determiner, such as *the*.

An example could be:

*The the that precedes a consonant sound is pronounced /ðə/, but the the that precedes a vowel sound is pronounced /ði/*

This makes *the* different than some other determiners, which can be repeated in various other contexts.

As Peter Jennings reminds us in another comment, *that* can be a determiner or a conjunction, or both in one sentence:

*I know that (conjunction) that (determiner) use is different*

Other determiners, like *many* can be repeated for emphasis:

*Many, many words can have more than one use*

This pattern may actually apply to *the* in one special (informal) case, where it's used as a kind of intensifier:

*This is the, the, THE best book I've ever read.*

I'm not sure that I've ever heard this usage, but I don't think it would sound particularly unnatural.